# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, array givenというエラーについて

Tags: php

度々失礼します。

htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 2 to be long, array givenというエラーが出たので解決策をしらべていたのですが、文字列を入れるべきところを配列を入れてしまっていることが原因だとは分かりました。

しかし、参考にさせていただいたところには「配列でも処理できるようになっています」と書かれています。

配列を入れたらエラーが出るのに、配列でも処理できるようになっているというのはどういう事なのでしょうか？

HTMLでのエスケープを処理する関数として、以下のコードを書いています。

```
<?php
//htmlでのエスケープ処理
function h($var)
{
    if(is_array($var)){
        return array_map('h',$var);
    }else{
        return htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
    }
}
?>
```

ちなみにですが、このコードの書かれたファイルを実行してもブラウザは真っ白な状態でなにも表示されません。

本体(？)もといエラーメッセージの出たコードの部分は

```
<?php
//  HTTPヘッダーで文字コードを指定
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8");
?>
<?php

//h()関数の読み込み
require_once 'h.php';
//checkinput()関数の読み込み
require_once 'checkinput.php';

//POSTされたデータのチェック
$_POST = checkinput($_POST);

//三項演算子で検索文字列の有無を判定し処理
$data = isset($_POST['data']) ? trim($_POST['data']) : '';
//入力された検索文字列をexplode()関数で半角スペースで区切って配列に代入
//全角スペースはmb_convert_kana()関数で半角スペースに変換
$datalist = explode(' ', mb_convert_kana($data, 's'));
//値が空の要素を削除
$datalist = array_filter($datalist,function($val){
    return $val != '';
});
//値でソートしてキーを0から振り直す
sort($datalist);

?>
```

となっており、エラーメッセージにはon line 6 と書かれています。

初心者で申し訳ないですが、力を貸していただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。

追記

checkinput.phpの中身は以下のとおりです。

```
<?php

//htmlでのエスケープ処理
function checkinput($var){
    if(is_array($var)){
        return htmlspecialchars('checkinput',$var);
    }else{
        //magic_quotes_gpcへの対策
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
            $var = stripslashes($var);
        }
        //nullバイト攻撃対策
        //nullバイトを含む制御文字が含まれていないかをチェック（最大1000文字）
        if(preg_match('/\A[\r\n\t[:^cntrl:]]{0,1000}\z/u',$var) == 0){
            die('不正な入力です。');
        }
        //文字エンコードの確認
        if(!mb_check_encoding($var,'UTF-8')){
            die('不正な入力です。');
        }

        return $var;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: もしかして、checkinput.php の中でも「array_map('h',$var);」として呼び出していませんか？

Comment: いえ、呼び出していません。
if(is_array($var)){
  return htmlspecialchars('checkinput',$var);
 }else{
といった記述はあります。

Comment: htmlspecialchars() の第2引数には ENT_QUOTES などの定数を渡すので、$var を渡していることが原因です。

Comment: ええと、「htmlspecialchars('checkinput',$var);」ではなくて、「array_map('h', $var);」でよいのではないでしょうか。h関数内の「if(is_array...」の部分は削って htmlspecialchars だけで十分かと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

すでにいくつかコメントでも指摘されていますが、エラーはhtmlspecialcharsに渡す引数が正しくないことが原因です。
checkinput.phpに書かれたhtmlspechailcharsの2番目の引数が原因でしょう。

正しい引数はマニュアルで確認できます。

- http://php.net/manual/ja/function.htmlspecialchars.php

htmlspecialchars自体には配列で処理する機能はありません。
質問者さんが参考にしているh関数にそのような対応があるようです。

質問者さんはどういった用途でこちらのコードを書いているのでしょうか。
文字コードやセキュリティを考慮した実装をしようとしているようですが、こういった処理を自作して万全にすることはかなりの手間がかかります。

一般的にはこういった処理はフレームワークやライブラリに任せると一定のクオリティのコードをすぐに利用できて安心です。

Comment: そもそもhtmlspecialcharsの書き方について理解が足りておらず、第2引数に本来入れるべき定数を入れてない事が原因でした。
それと同時に、checkinput.phpに、本来array_map('h', $var);と記述するところをhtmlspecialcharsの記述が書かれていたこと、逆にh.phpにhtmlspecialcharsの記述がなかったことが原因でした。

checkinput.phpとh.phpのコードは、参考にさせて頂いたところに用意しておくべきだと書かれていたので、コードもそのまま使わせてもらって書いていました。
htmlspecialchars自体は何度も利用しているのですが、このようなファイルを分けた書き方は初めてだったのでしっかりと理解できていませんでした。
今回のエラーは解決しましたが、未だ理解には至っていないので、ご指摘頂いたワークフレームなどと合わせてさらり勉強していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

checkinput.phpのhtmlspecialcharsは、array_mapの間違いではないでしょうか。